# Is there a way to set the initial height of an element in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react component that allows for a resizable text area based on the text inside.

```
return (<div className={`resizable-textbox ${className}`}>
   <textarea
      value={value}
      onChange={onChangeMade}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      readOnly={readOnly} />
</div>);
```

The onChangeMade method looks like this:

```
const onChangeMade = (e) => {
  const scrollHeightPadded = e.target.scrollHeight;

  if ((scrollHeightPadded + "px") !== e.target.style.height) {
    e.target.style.height = 0;
    const height = Math.max(scrollHeightPadded, 31) + 3;
    e.target.style.height = `${height}px`;
  }
}
```

This is a slightly ugly method I know, needs cleaning up. However I want to call this method once on the first load of the component but `e` is an event triggered by the `textarea` tag.

Is there a way to hook into this or directly into the `component` with the method? (I am using `React` `Hooks` and stateless `components`).

Thanks.

Comment: use css for the initial height?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) to create a ref and give it to the `ref` prop of your `textarea` and use that instead of the event.

**Example**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onChangeMade();
  }

  onChangeMade = () => {
    const { current } = this.ref;
    const scrollHeightPadded = current.scrollHeight;

    if (scrollHeightPadded + "px" !== current.style.height) {
      current.style.height = 0;
      const height = Math.max(scrollHeightPadded, 31) + 3;
      current.style.height = `${height}px`;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`resizable-textbox ${className}`}>
        <textarea
          ref={this.ref}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChangeMade}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          readOnly={readOnly}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```